# Rails custom environment Resque.enqueue does not create jobs

Tags: redis, resque

I'm using `Resque` for a couple of asynchronous jobs. I've set up a custom environment `integration` which is a clone of my `production` environment. However, my `Resque` jobs do not get added to `Redis` in my `integration` environment.

For example, if I run the following:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails console
> Resque.enqueue(MyLovelyJob, 1)
```

I will see the job appear in resque-web.

But, if I run the following:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=integration rails console
> Resque.enqueue(MyLovelyJob, 1)
```

The job does not appear in resque-web.

Clearly I'm missing some kind of configuration, I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

few expectations first.

You have a `config/resque_config.rb` or similar like:

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'resque' # include resque so we can configure it
require 'resque/server'
require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'
require 'yaml'

Resque.redis.namespace = "resque:api"

rails_root = ENV['APP_ROOT'] || (File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/..')
# require File.expand_path(File.join(rails_root,"lib","extensions","resque","worker.rb"))

rails_env = RAILS_ENV if defined? RAILS_ENV
rails_env ||= ( ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development' )

resque_config = YAML.load_file(File.join(rails_root, 'config/resque.yml'))
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]

# IN THIS ORDER
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.join(rails_root, 'config/resque_schedule.yml')) # load the schedule
```

and a `config/resque.yml` or similar like:

```
development: localhost:6379
test: localhost:6379
integration: localhost:6379
staging: localhost:6379
production: localhost:6379
```

The `integration` would either be on / communicate with a different server or use a different port. Then you'd have it run it's own Redis server so that the 2 aren't overlapping.
I presume you didn't want production and integration queueing things to the same place?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix the problem:

I created `config/initializers/resque.rb` with the following content:

```
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque.yml')
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
```

I also created `config/resque.yml` with the following content (obviously these should be set to whatever is appropriate):

```
development: localhost:6379
test: localhost:6379
integration: localhost:6379
staging: localhost:6379
production: localhost:6379
```